# Find linearly independent vectors formally

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

How can I find $3$ vectors $a$, $b$ and $c$ in $\mathbb R^3$ such that $\{a, b\}$, $\{a, c\}$ and $\{b, c\}$ are each linearly independent sets of vectors, but the set $\{a, b, c\}$ is linearly dependent.

I would appreciate steps to go about doing this formerly with an example.
As I can already find an answer by guessing and checking.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: It can be easily be reduced to a simpler problem: find three vectors $a,b,c$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\{a,b\}$, $\{a,c\}$ and $\{b,c\}$ are each linearly independent sets. Once you've found those vectors, simply include $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider two linearly independent vectors $a,b$ and then pose $c=a+b$.

Comment: Please add an example.